# iOS app refuses to ask if want to register for push notifications

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is the first time this app has ever been installed on this device and it has never been registered for push notifications, but it refuses to ask.
Im using the following code, but no matter how many times I clean the project, delete the derived data, uninstall and reinstall the app on my device, it will never ask me if I want to receive push notifications.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

 // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Why wont it ask me to register for notifications? And I check notifications in settings and this app is not listed.

Answer (score 1):

Push notification is not supported on simulator you can only try this on iOS device.

1. Make sure push notification is enabled in your iOS provisioning for
   your *appID*.
2. Entitlements plist must include the key `aps-environment` and the value `development` as string when developing  and the value `production` just before submitting to the *AppStore* or before signning it with *ADHOC cert*.

To make sure that you registered to push notification include this
    in your code for testing if it's working

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
NSString *token = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<> "]];
NSLog(token);
}
```

If this does not work,try this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/).

Comment: I've got all that and I've done push notification before. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS**

For the first time a push-enabled applications, registers for push notifications. iOS asks the user if they wish to receive remote notifications for that particular app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again and again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

```
1.Delete your app from the device.
2.Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
3.Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
4.Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.
```

For more details see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html